# SQL Select: Evenly Distribute Results Set

Tags: sql

I have a table called `TableA`, with a `Color` column.

Nine rows total, if I `select * from TableA order by Color`, I get results set

```
blue
blue
blue
green
green 
green
red
red
red
```

how do I distribute the colors in a select statement, such that, the results set is

```
blue
green
red
blue
green
red
blue
green
red
```

Note:  This sample shows an equal number of each color.  I'm hoping for a solution that could handle a non-equal number of each color.

Here's another example:

```
NAME, eye color
John, blue
Joe, blue
Jim, blue
Jerry, blue
Jack, blue
Jamie, blue
Steve, green
Sam, green
Sally, green
Sara, green
Mark, brown
Max, brown
Mary, brown
Nathan, red
Nick, red
```

possible results:

```
John, blue
Steve, green
Mark, brown
Nathan, red
Joe, blue
Sam, green
Max, brown
Nick, red
Jim, blue
Sally, green
Mary, brown
Jerry, blue
Sara, green
Jack, blue
Jamie, blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a window function/subquery:

```
SELECT COLOR FROM(
SELECT COLOR,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLOR ORDER BY COLOR)  AS RN
FROM #TEMP_A
) AS X
ORDER BY RN,COLOR
```

https://rextester.com/FIJDL68429

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` in an `order by`:

```
select a.*
from TableA a
order by row_number() over (partition by a.Color order by a.color),
         color;
```